# How to get Edge window handle (HWND)?

Tags: c++, webview2

I created edge browser window using CreateCoreWebView2Host() method. This method is takes parent window handle and creates child window in which we can navigate the web page. After I am done with navigation I need to return my window handle, which I believe I am failed to return.

On Spy++ I see "Chrome_WidgetWin_0", "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "Intermediate D3D Window" as child windows to my parent window. which one is the child window handle?I thought I am creating one child window.

I tried by fetching window handles using FindWindowEx() passing above mentioned class names. But still not getting expected results in my project. So I doubt if I am passing correct handle.

Now the question is , How to get the window handle(HWND) for the window created by CreateCoreWebView2Host?

Comment: Have you used Spy++ to sniff what class name that child window has?

Comment: Yes, I did. The child class names are in the question.

Comment: @TippuR Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Chris : I created another child window in which I launched edge browser. The function returns the child window handle.

Comment: Was that handle able to return WM_NCHITTEST or anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebView2 SDK doesn't provide this HWND because exactly how the WebView2 connects up to the provided parent HWND is intended to be an implementation detail that could change as the underlying Edge browser or WebView2 Runtime is updated even when you stay on the same version of the WebView2 SDK. We're relying in large part on the browser's logic for rendering and so this may change in the future.

Instead of providing an HWND, the CoreWebView2Host (its been renamed to [CoreWebView2Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-538/icorewebview2controller) in more recent SDK releases) provides various methods for you to focus, zoom, and so on. What are you trying to do with the HWND?

Comment: The module that is calling my method handles the resizing window event. I am expected to create child window for given parent, navigate the webpage and return child window handle. Now I don't know how to return it as CreateCoreWebView2Host() is creating child window.

Comment: There's no supported way to obtain the WebView2 HWND to fulfill the interface contract you describe. As mentioned, unsupported mechanisms to obtain the WebView2 HWND are not recommended as they could break in the future.

If you like you can open a feature request at https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback

Answer (score 4):

You can get the edge window handle by using [`GetWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), passing `Handle` of `WebView2` control to it as the first argument and `GW_CHILD` as second argument.  For exaample:

```
public const uint GW_CHILD = 5;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

WebView2 webView21 = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(webView21);
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.Source = new Uri("https://bing.com");

    webView21.NavigationCompleted += WebView21_NavigationCompleted;
}

private void WebView21_NavigationCompleted(
    object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var child = GetWindow(webView21.Handle, GW_CHILD);
    SetFocus(child);
}
```

**Note:** You may find this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/185#issuecomment-636389400) useful. This is the trick that I've used to [focus the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259582/3110834) in Windows Forms as well.